# MS Graph API - Problems on SPO Mobile-App

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph, react-webpart

**The Background:** I am developing Sharepoint Online Webparts on-demand. Sometimes the functionality of these Webparts include the use of Microsoft's "Graph-API" to access Data regarding Office 365 solutions (one example being Microsoft-Teams data).
The WebParts are working just as expected in the Browser *(except IE 11 and alike)* on both PC and Mobile.

**The point:**
However, when it comes to the Sharepoint Online Mobile-App, the functionality relying on MSGraph-API seems to have troubles.

**My Diagnosis:** As my WebPart Project Setups don't seem to have Testing Capability (but some some sources like [this one](https://www.eliostruyf.com/writing-unit-test-for-your-sharepoint-framework-components/) suggest) I created a new WebPart dedicated solely to the use of the MSGraph API, testing various requests. As expected, this worked fine in the Browser but all requests threw/returned errors when issued on the SPO Mobile-App.

**The Question:** Has anyone had similar experiences and maybe found a solution to this problem? I am requesting a microsoft support ticket at this point but maybe there's just some information I've missed out on.

**Regarding my setup:**

- I am using the **React-Framework**
- I am using  the **sharepoint-generator ver. 1.6.0**, **gulp ver. 3.9.1** and **gulp-cli ver. 2.0.1**. When it comes to setting up a WebPart for development, I followed  [Microsofts Tutorial-Line](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) for SPFx.
- I am using the **"MSGraphClient"**-class to perform requests as suggested in [this tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial)
- As mentioned I tested various requests. Those are for example the ones my functionalities rely on as well as some others which I picked randomly *(some are beta and some are v1.0)* including some samples from the [Graph-Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#). My Test Webpart is telling me if the request was returned successfully or not.

Comment: did you manage to resolve your issues?

Comment: Yes I did. I will create an answer with a link to the gihub thread!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So even though this issue no longer persists (as of May 2019), heres a link to the [relevant comment (solution)](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2521#issuecomment-487962439) I used to fix this issue. Long story short this was due to some problems on both AAD authentication and the client libraries so Micorosoft had to work on a fix for quite a while. As of now, the comment I linked to is the only solution to this problem and has to be done manually but they will implement an automatic fix in the time to come - as far as I know.